# "Apply" a transformation in RaphaelJs

Tags: javascript, graphics, web, svg, raphael

I've written a wrapper class around RaphaelElement. It has a property elem which stores the corresponding Element and the two convenience methods setPos and getPos. Moreover there's a position member with the two entries x and y.

Therefore getPos() merely returns the position. setPos accepts a new position as a parameter and has to update the coordinates of elem.

Unfortunately there is no information what type of RaphaelElement will be stored in elem, it could be a circle as well as a rectangle. Right now the code inside setPos looks like this:

```
//position is the parameter, this.pos is the member
this.pos = position;
this.elem.attr("x",this.pos.x);
this.elem.attr("y",this.pos.y);
this.elem.attr("cx", this.pos.x);
this.elem.attr("cy", this.pos.y);
```

This feels like a dirty workaround. It works with both circles and rectangles, but on a rectangle there's no attribute "cx" or "cy" and on a circle both "x" and "y" don't exist.

I browsed the documentation for a better way to modify the position of a RaphaelElement and found the method transform. But there's a problem: I haven't found a way to give "absolute" new coordinates to transform. It only offers means to translate, rotate or scale. If I have to change the position by applying a translation from my current position to the new position, then I have to append a new translation to the transformation string. I fear that it might grow VERY long. Moreover, I would have to evaluate an increasingly long string to get my current position.

It certainly is possible to move my Elements by appending new translations to the transformation but I would like to be able to either set the new position directly or to "apply" or "finalise" a transformation, so that it's string doesn't grow infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consolidate method on a [TransformList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransformList) will convert a list of transforms into a single matrix. You could call this after you've added your translation.

Alternatively you could call getItem on the transformList which will give you an SVGTransform object and you can call setTranslate on that which would set the new position directly. You'd need to be careful that there is a transform and create one if there isn't.

Comment: nice approach, +1 for creativity. however, this is only applicable for SVG, and we lose the abstraction offered by Raphaël over other vector implementations (e.g. VML).

Comment: I still don't know how to use a matrix correctly but I decided to accept your answer. I think that my matrix usage problems are a different question and the initial question is definitely answered by your entry. +1 from me